# KIF .xctest directory for Amazon Device Farm

Tags: ios, xcode, kif

According to the [AWS Developer Forum website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest.html) I have to upload a zipped .xctest directory to their service to have my app tested on their service. I have KIF running and working on simulator just fine. The problem is, I don't know how to get the .xctest folder so I can send it to AWS. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of searching I found the .xctest "file". It's in your app's DerivedData directory, just next to the .app and .app.dSYM files:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-xxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Tests.xctest`